# Devise register and login rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

By default with devise. After a user registers it automatically signs them in after sign up. Is there anyway to register a user and not auto sign them in and redirect to the login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `Devise::RegistrationsController#create`. You can see how registration works [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/acc45c5a44c45b252ccba65fd169a45af73ff369/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L24)

First, create a custom controller subclass of Devise::RegistrationsController

```
class RegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        respond_with resource, location: root_path # Change this to whatever route your want
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end 
end
```

Then tell devise to use custom controller:

`devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}`

Assuming `User` is the model of course.

Comment: im getting this error now . "app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else else ^"

Comment: Updated my answer. The answer wasn't a copy&paste as you need to set destination path after registration. I put `root_path` for now but change it to what you need